# How can I force an embedded map to stay in container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to put a map in my web page but its over flowing its div
I've tried to minimize it's width but it still overflowing the dive
Bootstrap Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="p-4">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-4">

          </div>



          <div class="col-md-8 bg-warning">


              <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d26610.33705707623!2d36.25777643698207!3d33.519789553048696!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1518e74d9556cc31%3A0x1ccf35bcb0a51b26!2sStory%20corner!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1629485063423!5m2!1sen!2s" width="400px" height="400px" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>


          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by overflowing? The map is limited to small width because the iframe doesn't have predefined width. You can instruct the width of the iframe to be `100%` using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `w-100` class to your iframe tag:

```
 <iframe class="map w-100" src="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `width` attribute of iframe to `"100%"`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="p-4">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-4">

          </div>



          <div class="col-md-8 bg-warning">


              <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d26610.33705707623!2d36.25777643698207!3d33.519789553048696!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1518e74d9556cc31%3A0x1ccf35bcb0a51b26!2sStory%20corner!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1629485063423!5m2!1sen!2s" width="100%" height="400px" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>


          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The iframe that you want to have inside that div element, already has predefined width/height values.

You can either update inline attributes or add some styles for the iframe container

`.map { width: 100%; height: auto; }`